# Allow Lambda function to run on home network

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Network configuration always trips me up but I was wondering if the following would be possible.

I have an Amazon Echo Dot, which I would like to configure to say turn my TV on/off. My smart TV will take http requests with some XML, so when I am on my home Wifi I can do this.

What I want to achieve is to have a lambda function send my request and access my home network to do this. How would I go about allowing this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, and as you indicate, this is really a networking question - the ASK part of it is straight-forward.

You will need to open a port in the router that is connected to your modem and 'point' that port at your TV.  Then you need some method for determining the IP address of that router, eg. get a static IP from your ISP or use something like dyndns.  Now you can execute that HTTP command to control your TV from the Lambda that Amazon invokes when you speak your command to your echo.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll look into the points you raised

Comment: When you say point that port to your tv? Do you mean point to the IP address of the tv?

Comment: Yes, you need to 'point' requests that come to that port to the IP address of your TV.  You should be able to do this in the configuration of your router.

Comment: if i cant get a static ip address from my ISP then is dyndns the way to go? a paid service right? which will enable me to access my home network (router) voa lambda as you have said ?

Comment: There might be other - free - options.  I haven't looked into it in years.  Also, you could just hard-code it for now - some ISP's will rarely change your IP.

Comment: cool, thanks... will just stick with that for now then... can i authenticate the port forwarding ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way of authenticating the port forwarding, so you are exposing your TV to the Internet.

Comment: @Tom makes a good point.  You might find HAProxy useful.  It's the centerpiece of my home network's single external IP, routing incoming HTTP requests to various internal tinkering projects on different machines based on the Host header, path, etc., and in some cases performing HTTPS offload, header rewriting, authentication, hairpinning requests back out to S3, and various other spiffy things.  It's sort of a swiss army knife for HTTP & TCP.  It's the target of my router's port 80 & 443 and unlike a TV, it's designed to be exposed to the Internet.